# How to fix "not declared in this scope" error

Tags: omnet++, inet

In OMNET++ with INET framework, I tried the below code to display the number of packets received for each node but got the error: inet/linklayer/xmac/XMac.cc:522:39: error: ‘srcAddr’ was not declared in this scope.

```
std::map<L3Address, uint64_t> recPkt;
auto it = recPkt.find(srcAddr);
if (it == recPkt.end())
  recPkt[srcAddr] = 1;
else
  it->second++;
  for (auto it : recPkt) {
    EV << "From address " << it.first << " received " << it.second << " packets." << std::endl;
 }
```

A function named getSrcAddr(), which is a part of a class, returns srcAddr. It is declared in XmaccHeader_m.h

```
class INET_API XMacHeaderBase : public ::inet::FieldsChunk
{
  protected:
    MacAddress srcAddr;
    MacAddress destAddr;
    inet::XMacTypes type = static_cast<inet::XMacTypes>(-1);

  private:
    void copy(const XMacHeaderBase& other);

  protected:
    // protected and unimplemented operator==(), to prevent accidental usage
    bool operator==(const XMacHeaderBase&);

  public:
    XMacHeaderBase();
    XMacHeaderBase(const XMacHeaderBase& other);
    virtual ~XMacHeaderBase();
    XMacHeaderBase& operator=(const XMacHeaderBase& other);
    virtual XMacHeaderBase *dup() const override {return new XMacHeaderBase(*this);}
    virtual void parsimPack(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b) const override;
    virtual void parsimUnpack(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b) override;

    // field getter/setter methods
    virtual const MacAddress& getSrcAddr() const;
    virtual MacAddress& getSrcAddrForUpdate() { handleChange();return const_cast<MacAddress&>(const_cast<XMacHeaderBase*>(this)->getSrcAddr());}
    virtual void setSrcAddr(const MacAddress& srcAddr);
    virtual const MacAddress& getDestAddr() const;
    virtual MacAddress& getDestAddrForUpdate() { handleChange();return const_cast<MacAddress&>(const_cast<XMacHeaderBase*>(this)->getDestAddr());}
    virtual void setDestAddr(const MacAddress& destAddr);
    virtual inet::XMacTypes getType() const;
    virtual void setType(inet::XMacTypes type);
};
```

The function is defined in XmacHeader_m.cc file as below

```
const MacAddress& XMacHeaderBase::getSrcAddr() const
{
    return this->srcAddr;
}
```

Would anyone suggest how to get ride of this error? Thank you

Comment: Error is self explanatory, it can not find `srcAddr`, maybe you need to declare it or import it properly

Comment: Actually, a function named getSrcAddr(), which is declared in header file, returns srcAddr.                                                                                                                   ```const MacAddress& XMacHeaderBase::getSrcAddr() const
{
    return this->srcAddr;
}```                                                                                                                                                     Is it the right syntax that I included in question?

Comment: You may have a function to get the source address but I dont see you calling that function

Comment: Yes, i am confused how to call it in this code. Map creating part was suggested in omnet discussion group but i am getting error with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well post the code of your function declaration and where is it stored? Is it  part of a class?

Comment: Hi William, i have posted the code in my question. Would you suggest now?